# Making table report from non-related GeoDjango models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, datatables, geodjango

I have this 2 models:

```
class BuildingStructure(models.Model):
    bldg_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    height = models.FloatField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    block_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    bldg_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brgy_locat = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    geom = models.MultiPointField(srid=32651, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.bldg_name

class FloodHazard(models.Model):
    gridcode = models.IntegerField()
    hazard = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    date_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=32651, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hazard
```

`hazard` field in the model has the following values: 'High', 'Medium', 'Low'.
I wanted to create a report in a table format(HTML) like this:
[image: sample result]

I tried this so far:

```
getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=512).geom
getgeom_medium = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=620).geom
getgeom_low = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=638).geom

response_data = {}
response_data["medium"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom_medium).values( 'brgy_locat').annotate(countmedium=Count('brgy_locat')))
response_data["high"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom).values('brgy_locat').annotate( counthigh=Count('brgy_locat')))
response_data["low"] = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom_low).values('brgy_locat').annotate( countlow=Count('brgy_locat')))

result = {}
for category in response_data.values():
    for element in category:
        key = element.pop('brgy_locat')
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = {"loc":key}
        result[key].update(element)


json_result = result.values()

return HttpResponse(list(json.dumps(json_result)), content_type='application/json')
```

The above code works fine as I am able to get my intended output. But as you examine it, I tried one `id` in each hazard type. So my problem now is to use filter to get all the ids and used it as reference in my GeoQuerySet. Any help will be appreciated. I'm trying to pass the data as JSON in my template because I'm using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

This is how I get all the ids for e.g. hazard type "high"

```
reference = FloodHazard.objects.filter(hazard='High')
ids = reference.values_list('id', flat=True)
    for id in ids:
    #something has to be done here...
```

Comment: could you please provide more context about your problem (e.g. what real-world entities are your models trying to imitate) and explain what info you are trying to display in the table (what are Brgy_locat, Brgy_name and what do the numbers in Low, Medium and High columns mean)?

Comment: I suspect there is more than just one problem in this code. For starters: I don't know if you realized, but your statement `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(getbldg)), content_type='application/json')` is in a for-loop. A function is terminated after the first `return` statement. Move your `return` statement 4 spaces back, and then tell me what happens. Note: You still have to make a list right before the `for id in ids:` loop, and append every `getbldg = [...]` loop filter content into it.

Comment: I updated the question to address the concerns. I tried running my code in a Django console with the loop and print it, it returns values but my problem is, I can't work it to display in my template/page.